# Formatting Excel (xlsx) to convert to JSON with arrays

Tags: json, excel, xlsx

I have excel data like this:

```
Province | ShortName | City
-----------------------------------
Ontario  | ON        | Toronto
Ontario  | ON        | Markham
Ontario  | ON        | Hamilton
Quebec   | QC        | Quebec City
Quebec   | QC        | Montreal
```

What I'm trying to get is this:

```
{
  "Canada": 
  [
    {
      "province": "Ontario",
      "shortName": "ON",
      "cities": ["Toronto", "Markham", "Hamilton"]
    },
    {
      "province": "Quebec",
      "shortName": "QC",
      "cities": ["Quebec City", "Montreal"]
    }
  ]
}
```

How can I format my excel sheet data so that I can use tools like beautifytools.com to get the JSON data I want?

I would want all the cities that belong to the province to be in an array.

Thank you.

Comment: So..... what happens when you use the excel to JSON converter at that page?

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid i get back each city back, not grouped by the province